# How to create multiples meshes (with naming) along a spline?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm creating road assets to import in my game engine. Roads can be quite long (~3 km), so I want to split the mesh in multiple parts.

Right now, I use a spline and a mesh with curve and array modifier.

I'd like to "apply" the array modifier, but instead of giving me one big mesh, I want it to be converted to multiples meshes with custom naming (e.g. "RoadXXPartXX" where XX are numbers).

This is the result I want (made by hand here):
[image]

What is the best/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful method that achieves a close result to your Quiz:

Select the first object hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and click the last one to select them all in the outliner, this renames your objects one by one but faster.

<kbd>Right Click</kbd> *Context Menu > ID Data > Rename*

You may copy the word 'Road' into the clipboard and then add the numbers

Comment: Thank you for the tip for renaming, but I also need an easy way to split the meshes after applying the array modifier.

Comment: Go into Edit mode, select (A)ll then P > Separate > By Loose Parts.